# Is it possible to send parameters to the PWA application

Tags: progressive-web-apps

When I open an app in browser I get token from URL query. After that I keep it in the local storage under the @token key. But after that when I create PWA on mobile home and open it the @token key gets empty. Looks like PWA has its own local storage scope. So, the question is - is it possible to forward any parameters to PWA from browser when we create this one ?

Url example: https://foo.bar?token=123 (I wont to get token=123 in the PWA)

My manifest is:

```
{
  "name": "pwa-test",
  "short_name": "pwa-test",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "lang": "ru",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "description": "pwa-fullscreen-test description",
  "orientation": "natural",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "vite192.svg",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "vite512.svg",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    "education"
  ]
}
```

Upd:

I found out what if I set manifest parameter start_url as empty string `"start_url": ""` its starts read url params in PWA in safari, but on Andorid devices it is stop working and just show the text of the manifest on PWA screen :(

Answer (score 0):

On Android both browser and installed PWA have a shared origin, so you can store the datas in indexeddb and read it from there once the app is installed.

On iOS browser and each installation of the PWA have a different origin, so you can't share datas between them. It's a pain for sure.

You have to rely on storing datas on the server from the app in safari and fetching it from the app in PWA (for example using a fingerprint with clientjs or the IP address of the client).

Comment: The Idea with fingerprint looks good !